# Display MySQLi's SELECT Results with PHP's Alternative Control Structure Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to displaying SELECTed data from a database using PHP's alternative 'control structure' syntax. Here's what I have so far...

```
<?php databaseConnect();

$sql = "SELECT id, title, content FROM posts WHERE slug = 'post-2'";
$result = mysqli_query($database, $sql); ?>

<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) : while($search = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>
    <p>ID: <?php $search["id"]; ?></p>
    <p>Title: <?php $search["title"]; ?></p>
    <p>Content: <?php $search["content"]; ?></p>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php databaseClose(); ?>
```

That is returning just the headings (ID, Title, Content) of the results, not the actual result. The correct number of results are displaying, which shows me that there is nothing wrong with the query, primarily the displaying of the data.

I have now narrowed the issues down to `<?php $i["id"]; ?>`, `<?php $i["title"]; ?>` and `<?php $i["content"]; ?>`. Can you spot anything?

Comment: Looked at your code, couldn't find anything wrong. Can you please do a `var_dump($i)` inside your loop?

Comment: By the way: global variables, especially those named `$i` are a bad idea.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer `var_dump()` returned the correct data from the database and `$i` has been changed to `$search`.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman do you know a good guide to get started with the OO version?

Comment: @DanielHarrin I'd suggest php.net as that is the "home" to all this stuff :)

Comment: [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) covers it all and more. It's not a huge difference even conceptually. Consider using short variable names for things that are used very, very frequently, like `$database` becomes `$db`. That's still a meaningful name yet a lot less verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a minute: You are not printing anything. That is the reason why nothing appears client-side. You need to use `echo` or `print`:

```
<p>ID: <?php echo $search["id"]; ?></p>
```

The other option would be to use the echo-shortcode:

```
<p>ID: <?=$search["id"]?></p>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why it's a bad idea to use `$i`?

Comment: I was referring to use a global `$i` (like available everywhere). You might not remember doing so, but other code uses `$i` (which might happen quite frequently in loops). Debugging such a thing is quite hard.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I will be more specific next time!

Comment: @DanielHarrin variable names like $i, while "convenient to type", don't have any real meaning. I see you have altered your $i to $search which reads better as its a bit more descriptive as to what it is. Would you agree? It's the ole saying... Name it what it is...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw yes that makes perfect sense. Never thought of it that way before ;)